# boost::interprocess::file_lock erroneous behavior when used with std::ostream

Tags: c++, linux, boost, boost-interprocess, filelock

I am trying to use [file_lock](https://beta.boost.org/doc/libs/1_44_0/doc/html/boost/interprocess/file_lock.html) for restricting multiple instances of the same program running at the same time (Implementing something mentioned in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5339606/5735010)). I am using `1.66` version of boost on `Linux`.

Before locking the file, I make sure that file exists (by opening it using `std::ofstream` with `std::ios::app`). I noticed one thing, if we close the stream, then `file_lock` is automatically unlocked and hence, allowing multiple instance of the same program to run at the same time.

The program below doesn't work as file_lock is automatically released.

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    namespace bipc = boost::interprocess;
    if (argc < 2)
        return 0;

    std::string path = argv[1];
    std::string lock_path = "/var/lock/" + path + ".lock";

    std::ofstream stream(lock_path, std::ios::app);

    bipc::file_lock lock(lock_path.c_str());

    if (!lock.try_lock())
        throw std::runtime_error("Multiple instance");

    std::cout << "Running" << std::endl;
    stream.close();
    while (true)
        std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::seconds(1));
    return 0;
}
```

However, the two programs below works.

Looks like if we have opened a file while trying to acquire the file_lock, then we need to keep that file opened till we want to hold the lock. If we close the file, then lock is automatically released. I am not sure if this is a bug. Can someone help me with the reason of such behavior?

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    namespace bipc = boost::interprocess;
    if (argc < 2)
        return 0;

    std::string path = argv[1];
    std::string lock_path = "/var/lock/" + path + ".lock";

    std::ofstream stream(lock_path, std::ios::app);
    bipc::file_lock lock(lock_path.c_str());

    if (!lock.try_lock())
        throw std::runtime_error("Multiple instance");

    std::cout << "Running" << std::endl;
    while (true)
        std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::seconds(1));
    return 0;
}
```

And

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    namespace bipc = boost::interprocess;
    if (argc < 2)
        return 0;

    std::string path = argv[1];
    std::string lock_path = "/var/lock/" + path + ".lock";

    {
        std::ofstream stream(lock_path, std::ios::app);
    }
    bipc::file_lock lock(lock_path.c_str());

    if (!lock.try_lock())
        throw std::runtime_error("Multiple instance");

    std::cout << "Running" << std::endl;
    while (true)
        std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::seconds(1));
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have found the reason. It was due to `boost::interprocess::file_lock` were implemented using `Classic POSIX File-locks`.

This [link](https://lwn.net/Articles/586904/) explains the issue with POSIX locks and hence, with boost file_locks.

> More troublingly, the standard states that all locks held by a process are dropped any time the process closes any file descriptor that corresponds to the locked file, even if those locks were made using a still-open file descriptor. It is this detail that catches most programmers by surprise as it requires that a program take extra care not to close a file descriptor until it is certain that locks held on that file are able to be dropped.

Looks like I should be either using [flock](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/flock.2.html) or some other platform library which uses `flock`.