# Which IPC (Inter-Process Communication) type was used in this situation?

Tags: process, ipc

A Firefox instance is running and we write this in the console:

```
$ firefox www.gnu.org
```

Then the link is is opened in an already existing window. Then immediately, the Firefox-process that we called in the console stops. The IPC here occurs between the process that maintains the already opened window, and the process that was started from the console by us.

We choose one from **Named Pipes**, **Message Passing** and **Shared Memory**. Which one is used in this situation?

Thank you.

Comment: It does not necessarily have to be a IPC mechanism, there are several ways to achieve this: [How to create a single instance application in C or C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5339200/how-to-create-a-single-instance-application-in-c-or-c)

Comment: You'd have to check the Firefox source code to find out. Or use `strace`